# Show special characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string variable with a value of `Löschen`.

When I display the string, it is displayed as: `L&#xF6;schen`.

How can I make the string to be displayed correctly?

Comment: How do you *display*?

Comment: It might be problem with your terminal. Make sure it has proper encoding

Comment: I believe we need some more details about where and how you try to display it.

Answer (score 1):

in which manner did you implement the javascript. Is it displayed on your website?
If you are displaying special characters like 'ö', 'ü', 'ä' make sure your encoding is set to 'UTF-8'. You can do that by writing `<meta charset="UTF-8">` between your `head` tags. For more about UTF-8 encoding look [here](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations.de)

Also make sure you save your files in UTF-8 encoding, [Tutorial](https://authors.ai/support/how-to-save-your-manuscript-in-utf-8/)